# Show a loading while a for loop is executing until finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, loading

I'm doing a word counter files with filestack and I want to display a loading while it's counting words and hide it when this finishes.

So I have this in HTML:

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none;clear:both;">
<img src="loading.gif">
</div>
<input id="ff" type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="<myAPI>" data-fp-mimetypes="image/*,application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" data-fp-container="modal" data-fp-multiple="true" data-fp-button-class="btn btn-primary l-align" data-fp-button-text="Upload" data-fp-services="SKYDRIVE,COMPUTER,URL,GOOGLE_DRIVE,GMAIL" data-fp-language="es">
<div id="result"></div>
```

And in JS I have this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){

$("#ff").change(function(){

    var out='';
    for(var i=0;i<event.fpfiles.length;i++){
        var n = i+1;
        out+='<a target=_blank href=' + event.fpfiles[i].url + '>' + '<button type=button class=btn-sc2><i class=fa fa-file-text aria-hidden=true></i> ' + event.fpfiles[i].filename + '</button></a>';out+=' '

        if(event.fpfiles[i].mimetype=="image/jpeg"){

            $.post("filecount.php",{
                url: event.fpfiles[i].url
            }).done(function(response){
                //functions to count words
            });//post               

        } else if(event.fpfiles[i].mimetype=="application/msword"){

            var link = event.fpfiles[i].url;
            var idfile = link.substr(link.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            var lcconvert = "https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/"+idfile;

            $("#dkd").load(lcconvert, function(){
                $.post("filecount2.php",{
                    url: $("#dkd").val()
                }).done(function(response){
                   //functions to count words
                });//post                   
            });
        }
    };//for
   $("#result").html(out);
});//#ff
});
```

I'm trying to put '$("#loading").show();' and '$("#loading").hide();' in any part of post functions but it doesn't work or only appears but doesn't hide when post functions finish.

I would like some help.

Comment: You should be hiding it in the `always` function instead on `done` because maybe the post fails, and `always` handle both success and failure

Comment: What you need is to store the AJAX promise in each iteration of the loop into an array (let's call it `ajaxArray`), and then use `$.when.apply($, ajaxArray)` to check when all the AJAX requests have been completed.

Answer (score 0):

The ajaxStart/Stop functions will fire whenever you do any Ajax calls.

As of jQuery 1.8, the documentation states that `.ajaxStart/Stop` should only be attached to document. This would transform the above snippet to:

```
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.show();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    $loading.hide();
  });
```

In your specific case:

```
$loading.show();
$.post("filecount.php",{
    url: event.fpfiles[i].url
}).success(function(response){
    //functions to count words
    $loading.hide();
});//post
```

Show it right before the call and in the success function or error function hide it.

Comment: I have another $.post ajax in my webpage, how can I do this with only those two specific ajax $.post?

Comment: So you only want to display it with these two and not to every AJAX request?

Comment: Yeah, because I have another buttons that execute another ajax requests.

Comment: It works very close, when I upload files loading shows then hide and it's still counting, I'd like loading hide when the counting finishes completely.

Comment: can you try success handler instead of done? Look at my edit

Comment: Ah I get what you mean.. Did you append $loading.hide(); to the very end of the done function or at the beginning?

Comment: It's the same, just faster. I put it at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I put  $loading.hide() at the end and it happens the same than before just faster

Comment: I would need to see more of your code. I can't tell by the small code you provided. It should work like this. So the problem is that it is still calculating but not showing the loading bar?